# Encoding in a in-memory stream or how does TextIOBase work?

Tags: python, in-memory, stringio, cstringio

I am currently reading the documentation for the io module: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.TextIOBase

Maybe it is because I don't know Python well enough, but in most cases I just don't understand their documentation.

I need to save the data in `addresses_list` to a csv file and serve it to the user via https. So all of this must happen in-memory. This is the code for it and currently it is working fine.

```
addresses = Abonnent.objects.filter(exemplare__gt=0)
addresses_list = list(addresses.values_list(*fieldnames))

csvfile = io.StringIO()
csvwriter_unicode = csv.writer(csvfile)
csvwriter_unicode.writerow(fieldnames)

for a in addresses_list:
    csvwriter_unicode.writerow(a)
csvfile.seek(0)

export_data = io.BytesIO()
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(export_data, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
myzip.writestr("output.csv", csvfile.read())
myzip.close()
csvfile.close()
export_data.close()

# serve the file via https
```

Now the problem is that I need the content of the csv file to be encoded in *cp1252* and not in *utf-8*. Traditionally I would just write `f = open("output.csv", "w", encoding="cp1252")` and then dump all the data into it. But with in-memory streams it doesn't work that way. Both, `io.StringIO()` and `io.BytesIO()` don't take a parameter `encoding=`.

This is where I have truoble understanding the documentation:

> The text stream API is described in detail in the documentation of TextIOBase.

And the [documentation of TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.TextIOBase.encoding) says this:

> #### encoding=
>
> The name of the encoding used to decode the stream’s bytes into strings, and to encode strings into bytes.

But `io.StringIO(encoding="cp1252")` just throws: `TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`.

So how can I use TextIOBase's enconding parameter with StringIO? Or how does this work in general? I am so confused.

Answer (score 1):

StringIO deals only with strings/text. It doesn't know anything about encodings or bytes. The easiest way to do what you want is probably something like:

```
f = StringIO()
f.write("Some text")

# Old-ish way:
f.seek(0)
my_bytes = f.read().encode("cp1252")

# Alternatively
my_bytes = f.getvalue().encode("cp1252")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but how would I to add my_bytes as a file to my zip archive?

Comment: It's probably worth creating a new question for that. Have you read the docs for the python `zipfile` package?

Answer (score 0):

## reading text from io.BytesIO (in memory streams) using io.TextIOWrapper including encoding and error handling (python3)

this does what io.StringIO cant

### sample code

```py
>>> import io
>>> import chardet
>>> # my bytes, single german umlaut
... bts = b'\xf6'
>>> 
>>> # try reading as utf-8 text and on error replace
... my_encoding = 'utf-8'
>>> fh_bytes = io.BytesIO(bts)
>>> fh = io.TextIOWrapper(fh_bytes, encoding=my_encoding, errors='replace')
>>> fh.read()
'�'
>>> 
>>> # try reading as utf-8 text with strict error handling
... fh_bytes = io.BytesIO(bts)
>>> fh = io.TextIOWrapper(fh_bytes, encoding=my_encoding, errors='strict')
>>> # catch exception
... try:
...     fh.read()
... except UnicodeDecodeError as err:
...     print('"%s"' % err)
...     # try to get encoding
...     my_encoding = chardet.detect(err.object)['encoding']
...     print("correct encoding is %s" % my_encoding)
... 
"'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte"
correct encoding is windows-1252
>>> # retry with detected encoding
... fh_bytes = io.BytesIO(bts)
>>> fh = io.TextIOWrapper(fh_bytes, encoding=my_encoding, errors='strict')
>>> fh.read()
'ö'
```